# correcting the cout execution

Tags: c++, sequence, cout

While using `cout` if the statement is `cout<<E1<<E2<<E3;` then there is no guarantee that the `E1` `E2` and `E3` will be executed in the same order they are written.

What can I do to make sure they execute in same order they are written without writing another `cout` statement or `endl` in between?

Comment: What makes you think the expressions are *not* executed in the written order?

Comment: You can switch to C++17 which introduces additional rules causing them to be executed as desired.

Comment: @cigien At least before C++17 the evaluation order is undefined there.

Comment: @BessieTheCow True, was just wondering what issue the OP has.

Comment: @cigien I have written one program which has the same problem question is here 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61403626/reference-not-changing-the-value-of-variable

Comment: evaluate it before and store it in `D1`,`D2`,`D3`, then print that, usually order of evaluation is not really a problem

Comment: @MrugeshRaulji Ok, please add that information to the question.

Comment: @user7860670 Right now I am learning from c++ primer 5th edition. Can you tell me some book as good as C++ primer and teaches C++ 2020 or C++ 2017?

Comment: @MrugeshRaulji Try this [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @MrugeshRaulji you should rephrase the question to emphasize your concern about the order of evaluation and not the execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best decision (or just a good one at least) but you can use Boost.Preprocessor:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>

#define COUT_IMPL(_, __, i) \
  std::cout << (i);
#define COUT(...) \
  BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH( \
    COUT_IMPL, \
    _, \
    BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__) \
  );

void use() {
  COUT(e1, e2, e3);
}
```

This makes C preprocessor create `;`-terminated `cout`s for you, providing guaranteed order of evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your << operator is redefined, this will execute in the order written.
The

```
cout << E1
```

is executed first with a return type of std::ostream (unless of course we're playing games with a different cout type.  cout is not a C++ keyword or reserved word).  This side-effected cout is passed to the next expression:

```
cout << E2
```

The processing is repeated for the next argument.
I'm not aware of any C++ changes to operator precedence.  I can't think of any way to play with the C preprocessor or play with other really obscure overloading techniques where you might be able to do some atypical operations.

Comment: As far as I know, the stream operation execution order is well-defined but the evaluation order of those `E`s is not (until a certain language standard).

Comment: If not well defined, then a type analysis on the return values from intermediate operations should result in a compiler error on at least one platform.  Assuming R-L ordering, E2<<E3 has to result in an ostream type.  Where did the ostream come from? 
This must be defined in the program.  Eventually, cout<<(some intermediate ostream) would be called.  What does that mean...unless the programmer defined the operation.  C++ isn't that cavalier.

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood my point: the order of writing values to a stream is well-defined but the order of computing those values (if they are written as expressions like `cause_side_effect()`) is (was?) not.

Comment: The light shineth.